# Azure IoT Edge Module : Error while Build and Push IoT Edge Solution

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I followed this tutorial step by step : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module

But at the step "Build and Push your solution" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module#build-and-push-your-solution) I have the following error in the terminal :

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I check the 3 points listed on the tutorials ("If you receive an error trying to build and push your module") but I still have the error.

I don't even know what file it is about..

Do someone have an idea of the problem ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I add all the terminal output :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    106kB
Step 1/14 : FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:xenial AS base
 ---> 8593318db04f
Step 2/14 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:aziotsdklinux/ppa-azureiot && apt-get update && apt-get install -y azure-iot-sdk-c-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 8bed4f396527
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:aziotsdklinux/ppa-azureiot && apt-get update && apt-get install -y azure-iot-sdk-c-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: When you use the command `docker login` in your code, are you sure the parameters that you put are all right?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the result is `Login Succeeded`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of the paths in your command cannot be found in the intermediate docker image. Try running a shell directly on the intermediate image using:

*docker run -it --entrypoint sh 8593318db04f*

to check */var/lib/apt/lists/* and */bin/sh* are actually present on the image. You should be able to manually run the command specified in your docker file.

I have found that quite helpful in debugging failing docker builds.

Comment: Still the same error: `standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`...

Comment: So to be clear, you logged on to the image and ran the command directly and received the same error? In which case, can you verify that those paths exist on the image?

Comment: I executed `docker run -it --entrypoint sh 8593318db04f` (with the correct container id) and I had `standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are building arm32v7 image, so what os is your host machine? Can you try to build the amd64 image instead of arm32v7?

Comment: Y'm working with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu (amd64) but my module will run on raspberry pi so I need to build for arm platform. If I build for amd, no problem

Comment: arm32v7 image could only be built on arm32v7 host machine. So please try to build it on raspberry pi